# How to make a user interface like Instagram/Keek/Vine

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder, instagram

I'm building my first app interface using Interface builder, and i app wanting to build an app interface likes Instagram. I know this question is very general, but anything pointing in this direction would be great.

Comment: What do they look like?

Comment: download any (or all) of desired application. reverse engineer them. remove the unwanted part from the model and controller layers, remove carefully the unwanted part of the view layer, carefully keep the wanted part of it, and the rest of it is the desired interface you wanted. easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF it is your first app, I don't think that is the kind of question to ask, but what I see from instagram app is:

- UIVIEW (parent)

  - UIVIEW (tab bar) aligned to bottom

    - UIButton (home)
    - UIButton (explore)
    - UIButton (cam)
    - UIButton (favs)
    - UIButton (profile)
  - UIView (main content), taking rest of space

Then have a view for each component

(home)

- UIVIEW

  - UIView (top bar)

    - UIImageView (logo)
    - UIButton (refresh)
  - UITableView, taking rest of space

    - Header sections are UIViews with:

      - UIImageView for pic
      - UIButton for name
      - UIImageView for clock icon
      - UILabel for time ago
    - Cells can be

      - Picture cell
      - Heart cell
      - Comment cell
    - Section footer are the action buttons

(explore)

- UIView

  - UIView for top bar

    - UILabel for title
    - UIButton to refresh
  - UIView for search bar (this is hidden while scrolling)

    - UIImage for search field background
    - UITextfield with placeholder
    - UIButton that is initially hidden
  - UIView for action buttons (initially hidden or bellow search bar)
  - UITableView for search suggestions (initially hidden)
  - UIScrollView

etc etc...

You can continue, is just matter of analyzing how views stretch, move, show or hide in each section; and knowing what can be done with native components and what is a custom component. I think you can continue with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do :

- Check these app well enough to understand what are the UI components
  they use.
- If not available in default controls search for some custom libraries .Search at
  [CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/) and [Github](https://github.com/)
- Make a detailed design layout .
  work it out